# grabbing the url from a page php is embedded in

Tags: php, dynamic, dynamic-arrays, ssi, toolbars

I am trying to create a toolbar on the bottom of my page using php. It should be dynamic and it should not include links for the page it is embedded in. When i use the following code.

> $path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

It grabs the url of the page toolbar.php. I am attempting to grab the page the toolbar PHP is embedded in. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

```
$full_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Or...

```
$page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```